# php not well formed?

Tags: php, xhtml

when my site loads, it stops half way because of specific php code.  When I try commenting out the php code, the whole page loads properly (input boxes, buttons etc.)

This is the code that causes the issue

```
<?php
        //if the add location button is clicked, the add location, the whole form will not be submitted
            if($_REQUEST['command'] == 'Add'){
                if($_POST['companyLocation'] == ""){
                    $errmsg="Please enter a location1";
                }
                elseif($_POST['companySize'] == ""){
                    $errmsg="Please enter a size for the location";
                }
                else{
                    $location = Location::instance();

                    $testing = $location->doesExist($_POST['companyLocation']);
                    if ($testing == true){
                        $errmsg="Location already exists";
                    }
                    else{
                        $objLocation = new Obj_Location();
                        $objLocation->set_Name($_POST['companyLocation']);
                        $objLocation->set_Size($_POST['companySize']);
                        $location->addLocation($objLocation);
                        $location->saveInstance();
                    }
                }
            }

//this is the part that breaks! when I comment it out, the page loads properly.
        $location = Location::instance();
        $location->deleteItem($_GET["item"]);
        $location->saveInstance();
        $location->listItems();
        ?>
```

Comment: What's the error that you get?

Comment: Actually, the PHP syntax is fine. Maybe you should take a look of the log so that you can see what's wrong.

Comment: Silly question, but how do I read the error log of apache in ubuntu? and I can only ssh, so I'm only using the command line.

Comment: unless Apache's been modified to send the log elsewhere, it should be in /var/log/httpd/error.log

Comment: Does anyone know if my coding method is "new" to php 5.2.10?  The server that is choking on the code is php5.2.4.  Just a discrepancy I've noticed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly answer but, I was not importing my classes properly.  So once a Object tried to instantiate from another class, anything below that instantiation broke.

Code was lacking an include_once()

Hope that helps all the newbies out there!

Comment: Error log can help newbies. Way faster than whole month of code reviewing.

Comment: turning error_reporting on would make debugging a lot easier!

Answer (score 2):

I doubt it's malformed code (a parser error) - I'd recommend turning on error reporting so you can see the error on screen, or inspect your apache error logs. That will likely show some runtime error. Without the error, or the code of the `deleteItem`, `saveInstance`, `listItems` functions, it's impossible to say.

Comment: if i comment out the last 3 lines, and leave instance, I'll still get the error.  here's the code for instance.

 public static function instance($args = null) {
        return empty($_SESSION['locations']) ?
            new Location($args) : unserialize($_SESSION['locations']);
    }

Answer (score 0):

Newbies, and experienced developer too, should allways put

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
```

at the top of the php main file, while developing on the dev server..